# Speeding up Levenshtein distance calculation in python with global variables

Tags: python, performance, variables, global

Hi I'm using python for a project in bioinformatics.

I have a function that uses the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm to calculate the edit-distance between a query and a read from our Next-generation-Sequencing platform. (both strings with the alphabet: 'ACGT')
My script works fine, but takes a long time to run, because the function is called more than a 100 million times in total.
In the function I use a 2-dimensional list with size MxN, where M is the length of the query and N is the length of the read.
Every time the function is called this 2D-list has to be recreated in memory before it can be filled with the calculation. I was wondering if I could speed up the process by creating a 2D-List as global variable, and then passing the handle to this List as an argument to the function. This way the memory would only have to be allocated once by the operating system.
Hope I made my question clear.
How much time does requesting the memory for a list from the operating system take. Is it significant?

Edit:
some sample code as requested:

The function goes through the 2D-Array and fills it with numbers:

```
import time
import random

def do_stuff():
    row = 12
    col = 12
    newlist = [[0 for _ in range(row)] for _ in range(col)]

    myrand = random.choice(range(100))

    for i in range(col):
        for j in range(row):
            newlist[i][j] = myrand

time1 = time.time()

for _ in range(1000000):
    do_stuff()

print(f'This took {time.time()-time1} seconds')
```

This code runs for about 22 seconds on my laptop.

```
import time
import random

row = 12
col = 12
newlist = [[0 for _ in range(row)] for _ in range(col)]

def do_stuff():
    myrand = random.choice(range(100))

    for i in range(col):
        for j in range(row):
            newlist[i][j] = myrand

time1 = time.time()

for _ in range(1000000):
    do_stuff()

print(f'This took {time.time()-time1} seconds')
```

When changing the code, so that the 2D-List is only created once, it only takes about 14 seconds.

Of course the actual function does some computation before inserting the number into the list. Let me know if you want the complete function, but i thought this might be quicker.

Edit 2:

So after reading all of your comments I think the best way forward is to use a class. I tested the code above in a class:

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.row = 12
        self.col = 12
        self.newlist = [[0 for _ in range(self.row)] for _ in range(self.col)]

    def do_stuff(self):
        myrand = random.choice(range(100))

        for i in range(self.col):
            for j in range(self.row):
                self.newlist[i][j] = myrand

time1 = time.time()

myinstance = myclass()

for _ in range(1000000):
    myinstance.do_stuff()

print(f'This took {time.time()-time1} seconds')
```

This is not as fast as the first example above anymore, this take around 17 seconds now.

And this would be the comparison with recreating the list:

```
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do_stuff(self):
        row = 12
        col = 12
        newlist = [[0 for _ in range(row)] for _ in range(col)]

        myrand = random.choice(range(100))

        for i in range(col):
            for j in range(row):
                newlist[i][j] = myrand


time1 = time.time()

myinstance = myclass()

for _ in range(1000000):
    myinstance.do_stuff()

print(f'This took {time.time()-time1} seconds')
```

This takes about 22 seconds now.

So I think I want to use the first class example now. Can you confirm that I declared the variables the right way? It now takes 3 seconds longer than before (first example above was 14 seconds), is this only down to using a class or did I mess up the variables somewhere?
Thank you.

Comment: can you attach your code as well, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As explained [Alternatives to Using Globals in Python](https://medium.com/better-programming/alternatives-to-using-globals-in-python-a3b2a7d5411b) you could just use a Global mutable (in this case a 2D-List.  Your function could have access to the list without use of the Global keyword or having to pass it as an argument to the function.  You have to import the module where the variable is defined to your current module as illustrated in the article.

Comment: Thank you fore the quick reply. Sample code is above. Thank you for the link. It was a good read. I have not worked with classes or mutables yet, but I will look into it some more tomorrow. My testing suggests that the code might be a bit faster when I dont' reallocate the memory every time the function runs right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my take on the performance impact by having the list enclosed locally in the function rather than "globally".

---

**Edit**: as pointed out by @DanD in the comments, I wrote (and deleted) before the more traditional way of stacks and heaps. This is not entirely true for Python. The Python Virtual Machine (PVM) only uses a *private heap* to allocate its objects. But the PVM itself has been implemented as a stack. Then Python uses reference counters (among other things) to keep track of the objects, whether they should be discarded or not. 
When you use your first example, the list object gets pushed onto the stack again and again and again. The previous list object gets its reference counter decreased, and then gets removed when the reference counter reaches 0. This is a good amount of overhead. 
Your second example creates the list object once, keeps the reference counter satisfied, and then the PVM can use that object each time you make your call.

So: instead of recreating the list object for each call and generating new references, the performance is gained by having only 1 list object created with the same references.

Here is a small example, which your first and second example in a nutshell:

```
# Creating a list of lists. Notice the reference ID's
>>> z = ([], [], [])
>>> id(z), [id(i) for i in z]
(2319201223088, [2319201319560, 2319201317128, 2319201318280])

# Overwriting the z variable with a new list of lists. Notice the reference ID's changes
>>> z = ([], [], [])
>>> id(z), [id(i) for i in z]
(2319201201752, [2319201354120, 2319201320776, 2319201318216])

# This is just to show, that the reference ID's are preserved, if you use the second example
>>> z = list(z)
>>> id(z), [id(i) for i in z]
(2319201357704, [2319201354120, 2319201320776, 2319201318216])
```

And for your original question: The OS is fast at retrieving a memory allocation, but it is hard to determine exactly in your case, since the PVM has two memory handlers: a [raw memory allocator and an object-specific allocator](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html). But this is not your main issue in this case.

Comment: That is not how Python works. It is a fine description for C. In Python everything is heap allocated. The savings entirely comes from creating the nested lists once rather than each time the function is called.

Comment: @DanD. I agree. The implementation of the PVM is stack-based and then they are using their own "private heap", where the objects are managed through reference counting. But the idea is the "kinda" the same. You are using the same pointer to the list, which keeps the reference counter in place. But I think I will incorporate your point into the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your detailed answer, this has been really helpful. Can you take a look at the new code above, using classes.